# method in Java to get all IP subnet detail

Tags: java, ip, subnet

I have a list of IPs from different subnets, e.g.:

```
10.181.192.18   255.255.255.248
10.181.192.26   255.255.255.248
```

I want to generate all IP details for such IPs, e.g. network, prefix (e.g. in such case is /29), maybe ranges etc.

Am I right that Java does not have such methods to generate such details?!

Comment: I believe [NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces()) and [NetworkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getInterfaceAddresses()) are the methods you seek.

Answer (score 1):

If those are 4 IP addresses, it is impossible to generate the network, network mask and subnet range from them.

If they are IP addresses for >this< computer, then you can use methods in the `NetworkInterface` API to interrogate the interfaces and their bound `InterfaceAddress` list.  The `InterfaceAddress` allows you to retrieve the prefix length which you can then use to compute the IP range.

If those are actually IP address + netmask pairs (as they *appear to me* to be) then you have the information you need already.  It is simply a matter of computing the prefix length from the netmask and the network range from IP and netmask.

I'm not aware of any Java SE APIs that do the calculations, but they are straight-forward.  Convert the IP addresses and masks to integers (or byte arrays), count bits, do some bitwise operations and convert back to the standard notation.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. the best one can do is take the mask and write some routines to coalesce the addresses into appropriate CIDR prefixes.  And  your're also correct about the lack of any classes to manipulate these addresses.  No dottedquad conversion, no mask to to CIDR conversion etc.  But the good news is that all of these are easy to write.